# Want to know difference in JFrames (BorderLayout)

Tags: java, layout, jframe, border-layout

I want to know what is the difference between:

> window.getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout());

and

> window.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

(window is a JFrame Object).

Thank's for ure answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the Java Docs...

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html

"The JFrame class is slightly incompatible with Frame. Like all other JFC/Swing top-level containers, a JFrame contains a JRootPane as its only child. The content pane provided by the root pane should, as a rule, contain all the non-menu components displayed by the JFrame. This is different from the AWT Frame case. As a conveniance add and its variants, remove and setLayout have been overridden to forward to the contentPane as necessary."

Use getContentPane()

I always create a new JPanel object and call `setContentPane()` to add it to the JFrame object